# how to add dynamic series in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am building one chart in my application using High Charts, my data is coming from database.My series name is "year" which can be 1 or more and based on the "year" there is respective data.
so what i doing is I am assigning all the series and data to a string variable with for loop.
and in the series section i am giving this string variable as [seriesdata].But it is not working.
If i am assigning the same values came in string variable to the array as static values, Its working fine. kindly guide me where i am making mistake.Following is my JavaScript function for the  same.

```
function ShowChartCntRecvdMonth(cntrecvdyears) {
        $.getJSON("/Navigation/CntRecvdMonthChart", { Years: cntrecvdyears }, function (data) {
            var year = [];
            var Qty = [];
            var seriesdata = '[';
            var seriesdata1 = [{ name: '2019', data: [3883, 3961, 3893, 3780, 4021, 3765, 3560, 4099, 3310, 3403, 3628, 3137,] }, { name: '2020', data: [3489, 3883, 3403, 3331, 2605, 949,] }];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (year.includes(data[i].CntRecvdMonthYear)) {
                }
                else {
                    year.push(data[i].CntRecvdMonthYear);
                }
                Qty.push(data[i].CntRecvdMonthQty);
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < year.length; j++) {
                //seriesdata.push('{name: ' + year[j]);
                seriesdata += "{name: '" + year[j] + "',data:[";
                for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
                    if (year[j].includes(data[k].CntRecvdMonthYear)) {
                        //seriesdata.push(data[k].CntRecvdMonthQty);
                        seriesdata += data[k].CntRecvdMonthQty + ",";
                        if (k == data.length - 1) {
                            seriesdata += ']';
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (k == data.length - 1) {
                            seriesdata += ']';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (j == year.length - 1) {
                    seriesdata += '}';
                }
                else {
                    seriesdata += '},';
                }

            }
            seriesdata += ']';

            Highcharts.chart('cntreceivedmonth', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'area'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Containers Received Chart By Year / Month'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                    title: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Qty'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value;
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    split: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        lineColor: '#666666',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        marker: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            lineColor: '#666666'
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [seriesdata], 
//Here if i am giving seriesdata1, works perfectly but when i  am giving [seriesdata] then it does //not work
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: pleasssse help somebody to resolve the issue, i am stuck here for long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required format for series in Highcharts is an array of objects, meanwhile, it seems that you create a very long string.

There is an documentation which should help you understand it:

API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

And the API link which shows how your output should look like:

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: Hi Thanks for the support, Sorry but i am new to the charts so kindly bear me. If i am declaring a array and  directly assigning the same value to the array, it works fine, but when i am taking this value in a string variable and assigning to the array then it is not  working. why?

Comment: How can i convert this string to the array?

Comment: Please get familiar with the general documentation of the array object in JavaScript and their properties or functionalities. You need to know/understand the difference between the array of strings `[ 'test1', 'test2']` and the one string `'["test1", "test2"]'` (which you are trying to create). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array